# Oracle Apex include page item in html href link

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex 22.2 and I have an html list where I list some links. One of my links re-directs to a page in my application. The problem is it will sign me out every time I click the link because I'm not able to append the user's session state ID to the end of the url. Is it possible to dynamically select and replace a variable in a html href link? So far I've tried using JavaScript but the url always returns `session=:P1_SESSIONID` instead of the actual value.

```
<li>
  <a href="https://myapplicationlink/my-apex-page?session=:P1_SESSIONID" id="myLink">
    Dynamic Link Name
  </a>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript">
  apex.jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var sessionID = apex.util.urlEncode(':P1_SESSIONID');
    var link = document.getElementById('myLink');
    link.href = link.href.replace(':P1_SESSIONID', sessionID);
  });
</script>
<li><a href="https://www.mystaticlink/">Other Relevant Articles</a></li>
```

If possible I would like to avoid messing with re-join session and application security options. The source of my page item is selecting `:APP_USER` from dual, which returns and displays the appropriate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bind variable syntax `:P1_SESSIONID`  can only be used in a pl/sql context - it has no meaning in html. To use a page item value in html, use the [substitution string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/htmdb/using-substitution-strings.html#GUID-A896A94B-DF69-4D53-B422-3256C09AE464) syntax (`&P1_SESSIONID.`). Try

```
<a href="https://myapplicationlink/my-apex-page?session=&P1_SESSIONID." id="myLink">
    Dynamic Link Name
</a>
```

There shouldn't be any url encoding needed - a session id doesn't have special characters